# Is it possible to vectorize procedural operations (for/if ) in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I wonder if the following code can be vectorized? Or, more straightforward, I am trying to match a number to several intervals, the result of which determines the update of a increment process. Thanks a lot!

```
pop_matrix = [10 0 0 0 0 0];
    rand_num =rand;
    divid = [0.05 0.05 0.1 0.2 0.1 0.1];

for i = 1:6
    if rand_num < sum(divid(1:i))
       pop_matrix(i) = pop_matrix(i)+1;
       break
    end
end
```

Comment: I'll post an answer with vectorized code, but could you clarify what you mean by "match a number several intervals"? I'm just wondering if there is an easier way to do this.

Comment: Thanks a lot,  eigenchris, for your fast response.

Comment: I'm second guessing my answer now. When you put the `break` in there, you mean you only want to check as far as the first interval that succeeds, but none afterward, correct?

Comment: @eigenchris You solution is almost corrrect. You just need to index into the right index : `idx = find(cumsum(divid) > rand_num,1)` and then `plus 1` that indexed element in `pop_matrix`.

Comment: @Divakar that looks right. I skimmed over the `break` statement without thinking about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot,  eigenchris, for your fast response. I first draw a random number, and then try to find which interval it falls in among the intervals, say, (0, 0.05), (0.05, 0.1), (0.1, 0.3), (0.3, 0.6),(0.60, 1) . Say, it falls to the second, then the second element in the pop_matrix gets an increment by 1.   Sorry, I made a mistake in the original post, where the elements in "divid" should sum up to 1.

Comment: No problem. If you plan on running this for many (say hundreds/thousands) of `rand` numbers, I think there is a faster solution using `interp1`. If you are interested I could edit my answer to include it.

Comment: @eigenchris, yes please!  I just test your code, it does significant run faster than my original and runs as fast as an another version where did the looping by brute force, simply using "if elseif ... else" to exhaust the levels. But it won't work when the size of pop_matrix go up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
pop_matrix = [10 0 0 0 0 0];
rand_num =rand;
divid = [0.05 0.05 0.1 0.2 0.1 0.1];

idx = find(cumsum(divid) > rand_num,1);
pop_matrix(idx) = pop_matrix(idx) + 1;
```

---

**EDIT**: A method using `interp1` which is about 10x faster, assuming you want to draw `N` samples from the distribution called `divid`:

```
pop_matrix = [10 0 0 0 0 0];
divid = [0.05 0.05 0.1 0.2 0.1 0.1];

N = 1000;               %// number of random samples to take
rand_num = rand(N,1);   %// generate N random numbers
dcs = cumsum(divid);    %// get cumulative distribution
dcs = dcs/dcs(end);     %// ensure this is normalized to 1
dcs = [0,dcs];          %// put a zero in front to create a new bin

s = interp1(dcs, 1:length(dcs), rand_num, 'previous', NaN); %// draw samples
pop_matrix = pop_matrix + accumarray(s,1)';                 %'//add up samples together
```

This process is basically sampling from the probability distribution defined by `divid` using the [Inverse Transform Sampling method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling), where `dcs` is the distribution's cumulative density function (CDF).

Comment: @XiaoYi The second answer should run faster than the first if you plan on using the code to draw many samples.